# Python, Save the allignment to an object to racall it

Tags: python, object

IN Matlab you can save the allignment or any variable as an abject from the workspace then recall it by command **load()**.

- How to do this in Python to save time of the alignment and use it later for other process?

  ```
  Alignment = HTSeq.BAM_Reader('accepted_hits.bam')
  ```

I need to save this object to load it in other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). In Python, you can serialize your objects using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module.

Examples - to write the object:

```
import pickle
data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
    'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
    'c': None
}

with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(data, output)
```

now, to read the object back in another script:

```
import pickle
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as input:
    data = pickle.load(input)
    print(data)
```

Assuming you run it one after another, the second script should print your object back:

```
{'a': [1, 2.0, 3, (4+6j)], 'c': None, 'b': ('string', u'Unicode string')}
```

`pickle` can be used to serialize almost anything, from simple lists to complex objects. I wouldn't serialize anything that has to do with volatile stuff such as database connections, socket numbers etc.